# On navigation drawer item click, new list view in navigation drawer

Tags: android, listview, navigation, slider, navigation-drawer

I am trying to get the following functionality in navigation drawer but i am        not able to break it.

**scenario:-**

I am having a Navigation Drawer. On clicking any item in the navigation drawer I need a list view to open with multiple item in it, which could be further selected for some kind of functionality.
I am also attaching the Image which will Define my need in appropriate manner. Please have a kind reference of the Image to get What I basically and actually need.[image: navigation drawer with multiple list]

Any help would be appreciated..!

Comment: Why don't you want to use `ExpandableListView` for example? It will be the best practice for that what you want.

Comment: you didn't mention what didn't break in your scenario? You want a list of City on the right? or you want the menu list to be expanded? Please explain more

Comment: Worst case solution would be, to use two list view with linear layout orientation as horizontal and set visibility visible and gone as per requirement. But I'd like to suggest you to use rom4ek solution.

Comment: Could your post your codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i Have see your image what i understand is that, **from your drawer click you want another list appear it's right side . am I correct ?**
**If I correct** then **it is not possible using ExpandableListView** becuase **ExpandableListView will generate the item below the clicked item.**

So one solution is that **You can take two ListView.**

**First ListView inside drawer** and **Second one on your main content** and create custom adapter for both ListView.

Now **when user click drawer list item, identify which option is clicked** like City, MyNews or whatever.

**After identifying the click you can fill your adapter for second ListView according to which option is clickd by user. and apply that adapter to second ListView and notify it.**

So when user click on another item from drawer the same thing going to happen. But the data for second ListView are going to change.

I hope you understand what I am saying and It helps you.

**[update]**

Ok so your xml shuold look like this.

**Note: I am just writing a skeleton for this.**

```
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ListView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/list1">
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/list2">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now On Your java side. consider both listview are referenced as **list1** and **list2** , and you have created two adapter **adapter1** and **adapter2**.

Make Item click for **list1** and apply the logic like below ...

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

        // now here you can get which option is clicked from list1.
        // using position and 
        int your_type = pos;

        adapter2.filderDataAccordingToType(your_type);
        // create the above method in your second adapter and pass your type like MyNews, City or any other.
        // and apply the logic of filtering by passing type to your method
        // your_type could be any data type i have take the integer.
        // and after filtering data you can notify your adapter.
        // so when the data of adpater gets changed your secondlistview get refreshed.
    }
});
```

that's it.
**I hope it helps you.**

Comment: well it could be helpful though. put Linear layour with horizontal list view in drawer and rest your logic. if you can currect it please do so. so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: I am just little bit confused that you want both listview together on drawer or one listview on drawer and another one outside the drawer ..? So that i can update answer properly...

Comment: But bro if you are taking two listview side by side on a single drawer. it will give you much less space to user which is not good idea as a UX part otherwise you can go for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Android Developers tutorial on [creating a navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), but instead of using ListView, you go for an `ExpandableListView`.

For example, in that tutorial, you can see that in the first block of code they are using a `ListView`. Instead of that, change it to something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How to implement a ExpandableListView adapter is well explained in [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) tutorial available at Android Hive. I'm not pasting their code here because it's a long tutorial. Comment bellow if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

here is my code.

- i am using recycler view for child item.
- it is expanding down words.
- i am using 2 library.

  compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.7.1'
  compile 'com.wnafee:vector-compat:1.0.5'

here is Navigation Drawer Fragment

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {


private static final String SAVED_STATE_EXPANDABLE_ITEM_MANAGER = "RecyclerViewExpandableItemManager";

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
 * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = -1;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

private Subscription subscription;

@Inject CategoryService categoryService;

private MyExpandableItemAdapter expandableItemAdapter;
private RecyclerView.Adapter wrappedAdapter;
private RecyclerViewExpandableItemManager expandableItemManager;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DelhiShopApplication.component().inject(this);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    if (mCurrentSelectedPosition != -1) {
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final Parcelable eimSavedState = (savedInstanceState != null) ? savedInstanceState.getParcelable(SAVED_STATE_EXPANDABLE_ITEM_MANAGER) : null;
    expandableItemManager = new RecyclerViewExpandableItemManager(eimSavedState);


}

private void setRecyclerView(Category category) {
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    final MyExpandableItemAdapter myItemAdapter = new MyExpandableItemAdapter(category);
    wrappedAdapter = expandableItemManager.createWrappedAdapter(myItemAdapter);


    final GeneralItemAnimator animator = new RefactoredDefaultItemAnimator();

    // Change animations are enabled by default since support-v7-recyclerview v22.
    // Need to disable them when using animation indicator.
    animator.setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(wrappedAdapter);  // requires *wrapped* adapter
    mDrawerList.setItemAnimator(animator);
    mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(false);

    // additional decorations
    //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
```

//        if (supportsViewElevation()) {
//            // Lollipop or later has native drop shadow feature. ItemShadowDecorator is not required.
//        } else {
//            mDrawerList.addItemDecoration(new ItemShadowDecorator((NinePatchDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable
//                    .material_shadow_z1)));
//        }

```
    expandableItemManager.attachRecyclerView(mDrawerList);
}

private boolean supportsViewElevation() {
    return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

public ActionBarDrawerToggle getActionBarDrawerToggle() {
    return mActionBarDrawerToggle;
}

public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
    return mDrawerLayout;
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    selectItem(position);
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 * @param toolbar      The Toolbar of the activity.
 */
public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    mFragmentContainerView = (View) getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId).getParent();
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor));

    mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string
            .drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }
            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
    ((NavigationDrawerAdapter) mDrawerList.getAdapter()).selectPosition(position);
}

public void openDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}

public void closeDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    if (expandableItemManager != null) {
        outState.putParcelable(
                SAVED_STATE_EXPANDABLE_ITEM_MANAGER,
                expandableItemManager.getSavedState());
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void setUserData(String user, String email, Bitmap avatar) {
    ((TextView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUserEmail)).setText(email);
    ((TextView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername)).setText(user);
}

public View getGoogleDrawer() {
    return mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.googleDrawer);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    subscription = categoryService.getCategories()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Category>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Category category) {
                    // sadfksdjf
                    expandableItemAdapter = new MyExpandableItemAdapter(category);
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(expandableItemAdapter);
                    setRecyclerView(category);
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    // slkdfj
                }

            });
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (expandableItemManager != null) {
        expandableItemManager.release();
        expandableItemManager = null;
    }
}
```

here is My Expandable Item Adapter

```
public class MyExpandableItemAdapter
    extends AbstractExpandableItemAdapter<MyExpandableItemAdapter.MyGroupViewHolder, MyExpandableItemAdapter.MyChildViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "MyExpandableItemAdapter";

private Category category;

public static abstract class MyBaseViewHolder extends AbstractExpandableItemViewHolder {
    public ViewGroup mContainer;
    public View mDragHandle;
    public TextView mTextView;

    public MyBaseViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mContainer = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.container);
        mDragHandle = v.findViewById(R.id.drag_handle);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        // hide the drag handle
        mDragHandle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public static class MyGroupViewHolder extends MyBaseViewHolder {
    public MorphButtonCompat mMorphButton;

    public MyGroupViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mMorphButton = new MorphButtonCompat(v.findViewById(R.id.indicator));
    }
}

public static class MyChildViewHolder extends MyBaseViewHolder {
    public MyChildViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
    }
}

public MyExpandableItemAdapter(Category dataProvider) {
    category = dataProvider;

    // ExpandableItemAdapter requires stable ID, and also
    // have to implement the getGroupItemId()/getChildItemId() methods appropriately.
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return category.getSubCategorySize();
}

@Override
public int getChildCount(int groupPosition) {
    return getGroupCategoryAtPosition(groupPosition).getSubCategorySize();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return groupPosition * 100 + childPosition;
}

@Override
public int getGroupItemViewType(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getChildItemViewType(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public MyGroupViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group_item, parent, false);
    return new MyGroupViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public MyChildViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new MyChildViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindGroupViewHolder(MyGroupViewHolder holder, int groupPosition, int viewType) {
    // child item

    final Category groupItem = getGroupCategoryAtPosition(groupPosition);

    // set text
    holder.mTextView.setText(groupItem.getCategoryName());

    // mark as clickable
    holder.itemView.setClickable(true);

    // set background resource (target view ID: container)
    final int expandState = holder.getExpandStateFlags();

    if ((expandState & RecyclerViewExpandableItemManager.STATE_FLAG_IS_UPDATED) != 0) {
        int bgResId;
        MorphButton.MorphState indicatorState;

        if ((expandState & RecyclerViewExpandableItemManager.STATE_FLAG_IS_EXPANDED) != 0) {
            bgResId = R.drawable.bg_group_item_expanded_state;
            indicatorState = MorphButton.MorphState.END;
        } else {
            bgResId = R.drawable.bg_group_item_normal_state;
            indicatorState = MorphButton.MorphState.START;
        }

        holder.mContainer.setBackgroundResource(bgResId);

        if (holder.mMorphButton.getState() != indicatorState) {
            holder.mMorphButton.setState(indicatorState, true);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(MyChildViewHolder holder, int groupPosition, int childPosition, int viewType) {
    // group item
    final Category childCategory = getChildCategory(groupPosition, childPosition);
    // set text
    holder.mTextView.setText(childCategory.getCategoryName());

    // set background resource (target view ID: container)
    int bgResId;
    bgResId = R.drawable.bg_item_normal_state;
    holder.mContainer.setBackgroundResource(bgResId);
}


@Override
public boolean onCheckCanExpandOrCollapseGroup(MyGroupViewHolder holder, int groupPosition, int x, int y, boolean expand) {

    Category groupCategory = getGroupCategoryAtPosition(groupPosition);

    if (groupCategory.getSubCategorySize() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // check is enabled
    if (!(holder.itemView.isEnabled() && holder.itemView.isClickable())) {
        return false;
    }

    final View containerView = holder.mContainer;
    final View dragHandleView = holder.mDragHandle;

    final int offsetX = containerView.getLeft() + (int) (ViewCompat.getTranslationX(containerView) + 0.5f);
    final int offsetY = containerView.getTop() + (int) (ViewCompat.getTranslationY(containerView) + 0.5f);

    return !hitTest(dragHandleView, x - offsetX, y - offsetY);
}

private Category getGroupCategoryAtPosition(int groupPosition) {
    return category.getSubCategory().get(groupPosition);
}

private Category getChildCategory(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return getGroupCategoryAtPosition(groupPosition).getSubCategory().get(childPosition);
}


public static boolean hitTest(View v, int x, int y) {
    final int tx = (int) (ViewCompat.getTranslationX(v) + 0.5f);
    final int ty = (int) (ViewCompat.getTranslationY(v) + 0.5f);
    final int left = v.getLeft() + tx;
    final int right = v.getRight() + tx;
    final int top = v.getTop() + ty;
    final int bottom = v.getBottom() + ty;

    return (x >= left) && (x <= right) && (y >= top) && (y <= bottom);
}
}
```

here is my list_group_item.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/commonListItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="96dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:background="#ffffff">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/drag_handle"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#20000000"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/drag_handle"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/commonListItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="64dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_swipe_item_neutral">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/drag_handle"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#20000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/drag_handle"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```